# Different values on scrollTop when scrolling with scrollbar or with scrollwheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop, jquery-events

I supposed there is a problem with capturing value of scrolltop when I am using mousewheel (mouse with scroll +200px on one step). Is there any hack for it? I would like to move my elements from left and right to the middle of the page on scrolling so every px on scroll down is 1px to the left or right but when I am using the mousewheel the value of scrolltop is jumping randomly...

Can be the problem that I am using conditional on scroll from 10 to 390?

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/m9k34m73/

CODE :

```
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    $('.section-header h1').css({
        'top' : -($(this).scrollTop()/3)+"px"
    }); 
    $('.section-header h3').css({
        'top' : -($(this).scrollTop()/4)+"px"
    }); 
    $('.section-about p').css({
        'top' : -($(this).scrollTop()/2)+"px"
    }); 
    $('.section-about span').css({
        'top' : -($(this).scrollTop()/4)+"px"
    }); 

    //Issue
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10 && $(window).scrollTop() < 390) {
        $('.section-profiles .petra p, .section-profiles .petra h3').css({
            'left' : -380 + ($(this).scrollTop()/1)+"px"
        });
        $('.section-profiles .petra img').css({
            'left' : -380 + ($(this).scrollTop()/.5)+"px"
        }); 
        $('.section-profiles .michal p, .section-profiles michal h3').css({
            'right' : -380 + ($(this).scrollTop()/1)+"px"
        });
        $('.section-profiles .michal img').css({
            'right' : -680 + ($(this).scrollTop()/.49)+"px"
        }); 
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing what you are trying to achieve, I think this [javascript library](http://scrollmagic.io/) will solve all of your problems.

You can find its documentation [here](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html), but is as easy as:

```
// init controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// create a scene
new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        duration: 100,    // the scene should last for a scroll distance of 100px
        offset: 50        // start this scene after scrolling for 50px
    })
    .setPin("#my-sticky-element") // pins the element for the the scene's duration
    .addTo(controller); // assign the scene to the controller
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I knew Scrollmagic before but I was thinking not to use it for now. but thank you.